# Cannot login Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I've setup a Jekins CI server, added my login to global credentials:
[image]

and then enable security of jekins as shown below:
[image]

However I always get "invalid login information" error:
[image]

Any idea what's going on?

Note, I just drop Jenkins.war file into the user directory and run it as `java -jar jenkins.war`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, the credentials section is only used to access 3rd party application (like SVN, Artifactory, ...):
[image]

You need to create your user using this menu (in the Manage Jenkins section):
[image]